# Joomla 2.5 module with editable title and content

Tags: joomla, module

[image: Editable Title and Content]

Hi guys!

I need to make a new module with editable (from control panel) 1. Title; 2. Content.
Should I make a "Custom HTML" module or this is a wrong way?
I guess, I need some extension.

Thanks in advance

Comment: this comes default with Joomla. Simply make a "Custom HTML" module, add the text for the title and content and publish it. It can be edited in the backend where you created it in the first place

Answer (score 0):

if your content doesn't have iframe, embed etc. no need to go for a extension or your own module.

if you are going to use iframe and embed tags, you can't use default "Custom HTML" module. because "Custom HTML" module is filtering embed,iframe etc. in that case you can use something like this

**Custom HTML Advanced :** http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-modules/16359

or you can create simple module with two field